# back button logs user out of app - angular

Tags: angular

Currently my app routing seems to remember the last page I was on when I click the back button. It navigates to the last page like it should so if I click on 3 different pages, it'll go backwards in that order, but when I first log into the app. If I click the back button it instantly logs me out of the app and I'm back on the login page. It feels really unnatural so I was wondering what I should do to resolve this. I was thinking a mat dialog that pops off and asks if your sure you want to log out, not sure how to capture the url when going backwards. state.url only `alert(state.url)` when going forwards

. Maybe there are other ways to solve it? Also when I'm logging in, the remember password popup appears, which gets me to hit the back button to dismiss it causing the problem the begin with. So if I'm doing that then other people would too.

I appreciate the help!

auth-guard.ts

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;
    const isAuth = this.authService.getIsAuth();
    if (!isAuth) {
      console.log("Logging out in AuthGuard");
      this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
    }
    return isAuth;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I think you could do this. The simplest way would probably be to write a check in your login component that looks at`authService.getIsAuth()`. Every time the component is loaded, if they are authorized, route them somewhere else.

If you want, you could also implement this functionality in a route gaurd, but you would need to implement CanDeactivate which will be more cumbersome to write. 
[CanDeactivate Docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate)

Comment: That works perfectly! I'm glad it's that simple. I thought I was going to have to do something with router snapshots or something lol